# Can an update statement use an insert intent lock?

Tags: mysql

The database encountered a deadlock problem caused by concurrent updates of two transactions.

```
LATEST DETECTED DEADLOCK
------------------------
2019-04-18 15:54:09 0x7f85cff7e700

*** (1) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 70678199277, ACTIVE 0 sec starting index read
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 137 lock struct(s), heap size 24784, 689 row lock(s), undo log entries 10
MySQL thread id 6314744, OS thread handle 140210780473088, query id 1764862374 10.32.94.170 m_pr_d090 Searching rows for update
UPDATE table1 SET  status =1 WHERE c_Id = 24671 and d_Id =1247910

*** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 12918 page no 4088 n bits 688 index idx_cinemaid_dcardid_status of table `mr`.`table1` trx id 70678199277 lock_mode X waiting



*** (2) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 70678199289, ACTIVE 0 sec updating or deleting
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
144 lock struct(s), heap size 24784, 721 row lock(s), undo log entries 13
MySQL thread id 6313652, OS thread handle 140212696508160, query id 1764862806 10.4.189.142 m_pr_d090 updating
UPDATE table1 SET  status =1 WHERE c_Id = 24670 and d_Id =1247910

*** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
RECORD LOCKS space id 12918 page no 4088 n bits 688 index idx_cinemaid_dcardid_status of table `mr`.`table1` trx id 70678199289 lock_mode X
*** (2) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 12918 page no 4088 n bits 688 index idx_cinemaid_dcardid_status of table `mr`.`table1` trx id 70678199289 lock_mode X locks gap before rec insert intention waiting
```

cId,d_Id is Joint index，Non-unique

session1
UPDATE table1 SET  status =1 WHERE c_Id = 24670 and d_Id =1247910

session 2
UPDATE table1 SET  status =1 WHERE c_Id = 24671 and d_Id =1247910

Comment: While there is nothing wrong with showing us the error output, you should also give us information about the SQL code which is causing the deadlock to happen.

Comment: session1
UPDATE table1 SET  status =1 WHERE c_Id = 24670 and d_Id =1247910


session 2
UPDATE table1 SET  status =1 WHERE c_Id = 24671 and d_Id =1247910

Answer (score 0):

One simple way to avoid an actual deadlock would be to use `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` before you run your actual update:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE c_Id = 24670 AND d_Id = 1247910 FOR UPDATE;
```

and then:

```
UPDATE table1 SET status = 1 WHERE c_Id = 24670 AND d_Id = 1247910;
```

Using `FOR UPDATE` should at least guarantee that two transactions don't enter the same critical section involving the rows targeted by your update.

This doesn't necessarily mean that things like starvation could not still occur, but it should avoid the formal deadlock.

Comment: I want to know why two updates will deadlock because of the insertion of the intent lock.

Answer (score 0):

The following explains why the two concurrent updates are deadlocked.

```
session 1
UPDATE table1 SET status = 1 WHERE c_Id = 24670 and d_Id = 1247910;

session 2 
UPDATE table1 SET status = 1 WHERE c_Id = 24671 and d_Id = 1247910;
```

(c_Id, d_Id) is a **NON-UNIQUE** composite index. In this case, under the default REPEATABLE READ transaction isolation level, both the row lock and the gap lock are required to avoid the phantom read.

Without any conflict, session 1 will eventually attach 1 row lock to the index entry of (24670, 1247910), plus as many as gap locks on the non-existing entries before/within/after the index (24670, 1247910) since multiple rows can have the same value on the column (c_Id, d_Id); Similarly, session 2 needs to attach 1 row lock to the index entry (24671, 1247910) and many gaps locks as well.

A deadlock might happen in the following scenario (in chronological order):

1. session 1 holds the lock on (24670, 1247910)
2. session 2 holds the lock on (24671, 1247910)
3. session 1 tries to acquire the gap lock covering the range (24670, 1247910) < (c_Id, d_Id) < (24671, 1247910); To do this, session 1 needs to scan all the entries following (24670, 1247910) before finding out the smallest element that is greater than (24670, 1247910). Thus it needs to attach a lock on the neighboring entry (24671, 1247910), which is currently held by session 2.
4. session 2 tries to acquire the gap lock covering the same range; Following the same logic, in order to know the greatest element that is smaller than (24671, 1247910), session 2 needs to attach a row lock to the index entry (24670, 1247910), which is currently held by session 1.

As you can see, both sessions are holding one lock while waiting for a second lock to be released by its counterpart, namely a deadlock. If you are lucky enough, the step 3 happens before step 2, there is no deadlock.

When the number of concurrent sessions is low, the dead lock is not a big issue since the InnoDB internally detects such case when the system variable *innodb_deadlock_detect* is ON. If a dead lock occurs, the engine will simply rollback the transaction with lower weight to break the dependency cycle.

If the above deadlock situation happens often your system, I would suggest to avoid querying the data by non-unique index. For example, add a **UNIQUE** index to the existing table and query the database by it if possible. When the index used is unique, no gap lock is required anymore, the sessions won't be deadlocked in the above scenario.

Comment: I want to know why two updates will deadlock because of the insertion of the intent lock.

Comment: Maybe I am not clear enough in my original answer. I've reedit the post with more details. Basically two sessions happen to hold one lock while waiting for a second lock to be released by its counterpart.

Comment: I can understand what you mean. What I want to ask is how the log is prompted to insert the intent lock.